# Chrome shortcut via AHK to reopen last page visited

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Which would be the ahk script to allow Chrome to open the last webpage visited? I'm not asking for the reopen closed tab, that is easy at Chrome, I'm asking a shortcut to open the last page visited when I reopen Chrome, without setting Chrome to do that as default.

Comment: `CTRL + H` `\tab \tab \tab \tab Enter`

Comment: @darka the last "Enter" is not opening that link, which would be the way? I'm almost there: I mean the right link is highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Here is AutoHotkey script based on [Darka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692632/darka) comment:

**Version 1:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinActivate, Google Chrome

CheckChromeWindow:
IfWinActive, Google Chrome
{
    Send, ^h
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckChromeWindow
}

CheckHistoryPage:
IfWinActive, History - Google Chrome
{
    Send, {Tab 4}
    Send, {Enter}
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckHistoryPage
}
```

**EDIT:**
**Version 2:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinActivate, Google Chrome

CheckChromeWindow:
IfWinActive, Google Chrome
{
    Send, ^h
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckChromeWindow
}

CheckHistoryPage:
IfWinActive, History - Google Chrome
{
    Send, {Tab 5}
    Send, {Enter}
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckHistoryPage
}
```

**Version 3:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinActivate, Google Chrome

CheckChromeWindow:
IfWinActive, Google Chrome
{
    Send, ^h
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckChromeWindow
}

CheckHistoryPage:
IfWinActive, History - Google Chrome
{
    Send, {Tab 4}
    Send, {Enter}
    Send, {Tab}
    Send, {Enter}
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckHistoryPage
}
```

If you want to run that code with hotkey (in our case <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) then put code above in place of `;some code` and after pu all that code put in the end of your script:

```
return
!^z::
    ;some code
return
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: it is not working:#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^!s:: 
        SetTitleMatchMode, 2
         WinActivate, Google Chrome
         Send, ^h
         CheckHistoryPage:
         IfWinActive, History - Google Chrome
         {
        Send, {Tab 4}
        Send, {Enter}
        }
    else
          {
          Goto, CheckHistoryPage
           }
      Return 
      #IfWinActive

Comment: @AMDG Please use pastbin like service for your code. Which code is not working for you, my or your? Which version of AutoHotkey are you using?

Comment: it was your code it did not work. So I tried to quote my script but sorry I was unable to makea code block. ahk version is v1.1.09.04

Comment: @AMDG Did you try my code without any other code? Because at lease that code is not my `#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ^!s::`.

Comment: well yes I just changed that the code should run in the context of Chrome and hotkey. the rest is the same and I pasted at this commment though I dont't know how to create a code block.

Comment: @AMDG I I added extra check to my code. Please check it again. Old version was working for me. I hope new version will work for you.

Comment: where is your new edited code? I don' see any difference. Remember that the code should work with a shortcut INSIDE Chrome.  Moreover i think somewhere at the code should appear a Click. I mean the result of the script should be that indeed my last closed screen appears.

Comment: @AMDG Code in my answer was updated, it has new code. What you mean by "shortcut INSIDE Chrome"? That code activates Chrome window, sends `CTRL + H` then `Tab` 4 times and after `Enter`. All that opens history window of the Chrome and opens first entire in it. Check my code without any other code, just open notepad, paste my code, save it as `anyname.ahk` file, run that file while chrome is opened.

Comment: ok I did what you told me but it is not opening the last one, it depends. I may add some sleep? Also please I would have it as another script at my main file ahk script with a hotkey when I'm at a Chrome. Maybe that can also help to make it really work.

Comment: @AMDG My code waits until windows are activated and only then sends keys. If it does not works, then as you said try to add `Sleep` commands.

Comment: your script only works for me if after it is done I press one tab and then one enter. Could you include that at the script? another question I want to have your script at my main script; for that should I add a "return" at the end and a hotkey at the beginning?

Comment: @AMDG I have updated my answer (look after **EDIT:**). I have added two new versions (Version 2 and 3) try both. After them I explained how to put that code to hotkey. If you have some problems with putting it in hotkey, then let me know, I will help.